# Undefined variable: modelRepository

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, magento2.3, magento2.3.0

> Notice: Undefined variable: modelRepository in
>   /home/server/web/server.dev.vendor.com/public_html/app/code/TemplateMonster/FilmSlider/Block/Widget/FilmSlider.php
>   on line 121

```
public function createSlider()
{
    try {
        $sliderId = $this->getSliderId();
        $modelRepository = $this->_filmSliderRepository->getById($sliderId);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        echo __('Can not load slider');
    }
    return $modelRepository;
}
```

Just updated to 2.3.0 and get this error when open home page, how can i solve this?

Answer (score 2):

This error comes because **$modelRepository** variable you have return but some how your try block not execute.

Initialise variable **$modelRepository** with blank before try block like

`$modelRepository = '';`

Please let me know still you are getting error.

Answer (score 0):

Your following code snippet throwing an error

```
try {
    $sliderId = $this->getSliderId();
    $modelRepository = $this->_filmSliderRepository->getById($sliderId);
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo __('Can not load slider');
}
```

That's why $modelRepository is null.

You can try the following way for fixing this error:

```
public function createSlider()
{
    try {
        $sliderId = $this->getSliderId();
        $modelRepository = $this->_filmSliderRepository->getById($sliderId);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $modelRepository = $this->_filmSlideFactory->create();
        echo __('Can not load slider');
    }
    return $modelRepository;
}
```

Where $this->_filmSlideFactory is the instance of FilmSlider model.

Answer (score 0):

Inside echo `echo __('Can not load slider');` directly from is not good.As per as Magento standard.

*You have to return this some value from catch block instead of echo,*

```
public function createSlider()
{
    try {
        $sliderId = $this->getSliderId();
        $modelRepository = $this->_filmSliderRepository->getById($sliderId);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
     //return from here
        return  __('Can not load slider');
    }
    return $modelRepository;
}
```